# Change a YouTube playlist thumbnail with the API

Tags: api, web-scraping, google-api, youtube, youtube-api

Is there any way to change a YouTube playlist thumbnail using the API or any roundabout ways?

I've gone through almost all of the YouTube Data API documentation without finding anything that allows you to do this kind of task.

I would ideally like to take the thumbnail of most viewed video in a playlist to set it up as the playlist thumbnail, without having to change the playlist sorting order (and without manual intervention, obviously).

Comment: I also have this question. I tried using the thumbnail().set() endpoint, which is intended for videos, not playlists, but I receive a forbidden permissions error. I arrived here asking a similar question as you.